# C: I have a simple fastfood transaction program, how can I automatically print a receipt for the food ordered?

Tags: c, receipt

Here is my code.. i'm really new to C, i have just started so apologies if my code is all over the place

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int item,qty=0;
float total=0;
char choice;

printf("\tWelcome!\n\t MENU\n");
orderstart:
printf("ITEM NO.\t\tITEM\tPRICE\n");
printf("1.\tFried Chicken\tUSD 7.00\n2.\tSpaghetti\tUSD 9.00\n3.\tBurger\tUSD 6.00\n");
printf("What would you like to order?(Enter item no.): ");
scanf("%d",&item);
printf("How many of the item would you like to order?: ";
scanf("%d",&qty);

if(item==1)
{total = total + 7 * qty;}
if(item==2)
{total = total + 9 * qty;}
if(item==3)
{total = total + 6 * qty;}

printf("Your total payment is now USD %f",total);
printf("Would you like to order more?(Y/N): ");
scanf(" %c",&choice);

if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
{goto orderstart;}
else
```

after "else" that would be where i'd put the receipt generation.

Comment: "generate a receipt?" Do you mean, how to print a receipt?

Comment: You could use an array to keep track of the number of different items.

Comment: oops, yes. i meant printing a receipt but automatically?

Comment: Automatically? You'd still have to write the relevant printf functions, and if statements or a loop to go through the various ordered items.